# Ajax get table value based on row

Tags: javascript, html

I can get first and last value from my row but can`t get the second and third value of my row.  can anyone help me.

this my code

=> Html

```
<tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>  
</tr>
```

=> javascript

```
$(".btnDelete").click(function (evt) {
   var cell=$(evt.target).closest("tr").children().first();
   var cell2=$(evt.target).closest("tr").children().last();
   var custID=cell.text();
   var custID2=cell2.text();
   alert(custID);
   alert(custID2);
}
```

thanks .

Comment: Is it an option to assign IDs to your cells and grab the information according to that?

Comment: no, it just a table row

Comment: I understand that, but if you are always going to have 4 <td>s in that row you could grab the info according to IDs instead of traversing through the table.

Comment: Is there also only ever one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easier to get this values without jQuery. By using [HTMLTableRowElement.cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) DOM property. Which is almost like an array, but not an array.

```
$("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
     // get the current row
     var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0]; 
     var cells = currentRow.cells;

     var firstCell = cells[0].textContent;
     var secondCell = cells[1].textContent;

     //...
     //nthCell = cells[n-1].textContent;
     console.log( firstCell );
     console.log( secondCell );
});
```

If you still want jQuery, then instead of `.first()` and `.last()` methods, you could use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
 var rowCells = $(this).closest("tr").children(); 
 var firstCell = rowCells.eq( 0 ).text();
 var secondCell = rowCells.eq( 1 ).text();
```

Comment: Also modern browsers has [closest method](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) in Element's prototype

Comment: i use the second choice. yes, this work. thank`s for help Arnial.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nth-child(n)` method

**Example**

```js
   $(".btnDelete").click(function (evt) {
  var cell2 = $(evt.target).parent().parent("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text();
  var cell3 = $(evt.target).parent().parent("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
  console.log("cell 2 : "+cell2+", cell 3 : "+cell3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i try  like this " var cell3 = $(evt.target).parent().parent("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)").text(); 
        var custID3=cell3.text();  
        alert(custID3); " . but give me null value. how i can assign it into a variable. any way thanks for comment Alexis

Comment: yes, it work. sory I`m new in js. thank`s for help Alexis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq(index)` to get the value from `td` by using its index. `Index` starts from `0`

```
alert($(evt.target).closest("tr").children('td:eq(2)').text());   //get value from 3rd `td`
```

Comment: this give me " null " result

Comment: Which version of jquery are  you using ?

Comment: sorry, this work. i make mistake when first trying. thanks

Comment: any way, when i try paste a your code. it show a result but when i try  to assign it into a variable it`s not work. this what i try " var cell3=$(evt.target).closest("tr").children('td:eq(3)').text(); " this not give me a result. how can i assign it into a variable Leopard ??

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         // get the current row
         var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 
         
         var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
         var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
         var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
         var data=col1+"\n"+col2+"\n"+col3;
         
         alert(data);
    });
```

---

If you want to fetch specific element inside div, then with classname you can do like this

```
$("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         // get the current row
         var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 
         
         var col1=currentRow.find(".classOne").html(); // get current row 1st table cell TD value
         var col2=currentRow.find(".classTwo").html(); // get current row 2nd table cell TD value
         var col3=currentRow.find(".classThree").html(); // get current row 3rd table cell  TD value
         var data=col1+"\n"+col2+"\n"+col3;
         
         alert(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to access every table data, just loop through your td's.

```
var cells = [];
$(evt.target).closest("tr").children().each(function(key, cell){
  cells.push(cell);

  alert($(cell).text());
});
```

---

On a side note, you can replace `evt.target` by `this`

Comment: i want for every row. what i want is i assign it into a variable.how can i do that ?