# Unable to get data from the second column of a table on clicking of the button in third column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which has four columns second being a paragraph field , the third being an input field and fourth being a button . What i want is on clicking of the button  row the data from the paragraph column should be applied to the input field i.e third row .

Its not possible to select every row using each function as every row is different and theres only few rows like this . How can this be done

I have tried this but it didn't work

```html
var or1 = $("#tab_logic button");
    or1.each(function() {
     $(this).click(function(){
      alert("u");
      var u = $(this).parent("tr").find('td:first').html();
      alert(u);
     });
    });
```

Comment: Could  you please share some HTML as it is necessairy to see how your page is setup?

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095769/ajax-get-table-value-based-on-row/38096402#38096402)

Comment: Side note, the each() off of the or1 is unnecessary.  jQuery will do the loop binding of click() for you (you should really use on('click') though).

Comment: Assuming you have a simple table structure, can't you just use `$(this).parents("tr").find('input[type=text]').val($(this).parents("tr").find('p'))`

Comment: Your code will not work button cannot be a child of a `tr` so `parent` won't work - try `closest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the exact HTML, I made this based on your explanation. If I understand correctly, this is what you want to achieve?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
 var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var name = row.find("p").html();
  var input = row.find("input");
  input.val(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Input</th>
    <th>Button</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><p>John Doe</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Name"/></td>
      <td><button type="button">Set name</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><p>Jane Doe</p></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Name"/></td>
      <td><button type="button">Set name</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```js
var or1 = $("#tab_logic button");
or1.each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    var text =  $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(1)').children().first().html();
    $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').children().first().val(text);
  });
});
```

```css
#tab_logic td{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab_logic">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><p>I'm just a paragraph</p></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><button>button</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><p>I'm just another paragraph</p></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><button>button</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```